# Swift 3 Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I am getting the following error while trying to do NSFetchRequest in Swift 3

```
Generic parameter 'ResultType' could not be inferred
```

i checked lots of links and i have not been able to figure how to solve it.

this is what am doing

**ViewController.swift**

```
func loadData(){
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Grocery") //Error occurs here(Generic parameter 'ResultType' could not be inferred)
    do{
        let results = try manageObjectContext.execute(request)
        groceries = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        tableView.reloadData()
    }catch{
        fatalError("Error is retriving Gorcery items")
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick introduction to CoreData in Swift 4: https://medium.com/swift2go/swift-meet-core-data-coredata-this-is-swift-9bd1952881d6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Grocery")
```

It should work :)

**Therefore your code should Look like:**

```
func loadData(){
 let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Grocery")
do{
    let results = try manageObjectContext.execute(request)
    groceries = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    tableView.reloadData()
}catch{
    fatalError("Error is retriving Gorcery items")
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, however i changed it to use NSManagedObject Subclass

Answer (score 2):

**Credits: Nitesh Patil** https://medium.com/@imnitpa/swift-3-core-data-7b00b50f5782

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as!AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        //adding new user and saving in database...
        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)
        newUser.setValue("Batman", forKey: "username")
        newUser.setValue("Robin", forKey: "password")

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved")
        } catch {
            print("Error occured...")
        }

        // restoring data back from database
        let request = NSFetchRequest < NSFetchRequestResult > (entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            let results =
                try context.fetch(request)

            if results.count > 0 {

                for result in results as![NSManagedObject] {

                    if let username = result.value(forKey: "username") as ? String {

                        print(username)
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                print("No results")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't fetch results")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this too:

```
let request : NSFetchRequest<Grocery> = Grocery.fetchRequest()
```

and you get results of the type [Grocery] when you execute the request:

```
let results : [Grocery] = try manageObjectContext.execute(request)
```

or

```
let results = try manageObjectContext.execute(request)
```